# Is there a way to decrease run time for nested for loop?

Tags: python, graph, nested-loops

I am trying to calculate `total_score` of each path derived. However, my current nested for loop takes forever to run when there are above 90 nodes, but runs well for just 20 nodes. I would need your help on how to make this code more **efficient** to run for bigger graphs.

I managed to retrieve all the possible paths (total of 7) from start node `a` to end node `i`. They are assigned into a list called `paths`:

```
[['a', 'b', 'f', 'i'], # 1st path

 ['a', 'y', 'f', 'i'], # 2nd path

 ['a', 'b', 'd', 'y', 'f', 'i'], 

 ['a', 'b', 'o', 'd', 'y', 'f', 'i'],

 ['a', 'b', 'd', 'o', 'y', 'f', 'i'],

 ['a', 'b', 'p', 'd', 'o', 'y', 'f', 'i'],

 ['a', 'b', 'p', 's', 'o', 'y', 'f', 'i']]
```

This is the `graph`, with key being nodes, and values being the neighbouring nodes the key node is connected to, with their respective weights.

```
graph = {'b': {'f': 0.1, 'o': 0.4, 'd': 0.3}, 

'y': {'f': 0.3, 'o': 0.1}, 

'i': {'d': 0.7, 'z': 0.3}, 

'm': {'o': 0.8}, 

'd': {'y': 0.6, 'o': 0.1}, 

'o': {'d': 0.5, 'm': 0.9}, 

'z': {'d': 0.1, 'o': 0.2, 'y': 0.4, 'o': 0.1, 'i3': 0.6},

'o': {'y': 0.8}, 

'a': {'b': 1.0, 'y': 0.5}, 'f': {'i': 0.3}}
```

*node b is directed to node f (weight=0.1), node o (weight=0.4) and node d (weight=0.3).*

**total_score = multiplication of all costs to travel from node to next node**
*For example, for the 1st path (a,b,f,i), the total cost is 1.0 (a to b) * 0.1 (b to f) * 0.3 (f to i) = 0.03*

This is my current nested for loop code:

```
def total_scores(graph, paths):
  scores = []
  score = 1.0
  for i in range(len(paths)):  # go into 1st possible path
    path = paths[i]
    for j in range(len(path) - 1): # go from 1st to last node in 1st path
      first = paths[i][j] # 1st node in 1st path
      next = paths[i][j + 1] # 2nd node in 2nd path
      score *= graph[first][next] 
    scores.append(round(score,5))
    score = 1.0
  return scores
total_scores(graph, paths)

total_scores(graph, paths)
```

I have thought about recursion, but i doubt it will help much in terms of runtime, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What are the metrics you're trying to beat here? Like how long does it take to run the code with 100 nodes?

Comment: So you want all possible paths or just the best one? Look at [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Comment: Graph problems are inherently computation-heavy. Traversing all possible paths has quadratic complexity on average (based on the graph's structure of course). If you insist on using this approach, I would say your best bet is using parallelization and running iterations of the loop in parallel. However, I would suggest using greedy algorithms while dealing with graph problems, if the problem allows.

Comment: @AC1009 I tried running with 97 nodes, but it has been about 20mins and seems to be forever running

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I just need to print the path with the highest total_scores. What i did was 
1. BFS to print all possible paths from start to end 
2. for each path derived, calculate total_scores for each path
3. lastly a find max score function that returns me the path with highest scores. 
I am actually looking at priority queues now, but not sure if it would actually work, facing some problems with it

Answer (score 0):

Python's lists are very flexible and very inefficient for this sort of computation. Replace your character node identifiers by numbers, and store the whole thing in a numpy array. That will speed it up by many factors.

Answer (score 0):

Although having a nested loop your code already as has O(n) time complexity, where n is the total number of edges in all paths. So if we limit ourselves to the standard library there's not much that can be done.

I came up with a ~40% faster version, but I doubt you can do much better than that: the idea is to store the edges instead of the nodes in the paths, and modify the graph structure accordingly (note some values were missing in the graph you posted, I added them with a weight of 1)

```
epaths = [
 [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'f'), ('f', 'i')],
 [('a', 'y'), ('y', 'f'), ('f', 'i')],
 [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'd'), ('d', 'y'), ('y', 'f'), ('f', 'i')],
 [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'o'), ('o', 'd'), ('d', 'y'), ('y', 'f'), ('f', 'i')],
 [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'd'), ('d', 'o'), ('o', 'y'), ('y', 'f'), ('f', 'i')],
 [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'p'), ('p', 'd'), ('d', 'o'), ('o', 'y'), ('y', 'f'), ('f', 'i')],
 [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'p'), ('p', 's'), ('s', 'o'), ('o', 'y'), ('y', 'f'), ('f', 'i')]]

tgraph = {
 ('a', 'b'): 1.0,
 ('a', 'y'): 0.5,
 ('b', 'd'): 0.3,
 ('b', 'f'): 0.1,
 ('b', 'o'): 0.4,
 ('b', 'p'): 1.0,
 ('d', 'o'): 0.1,
 ('d', 'y'): 0.6,
 ('f', 'i'): 0.3,
 ('i', 'd'): 0.7,
 ('i', 'z'): 0.3,
 ('m', 'o'): 0.8,
 ('o', 'd'): 1.0,
 ('o', 'y'): 0.8,
 ('p', 'd'): 1.0,
 ('p', 's'): 1.0,
 ('s', 'o'): 1.0,
 ('y', 'f'): 0.3,
 ('y', 'o'): 0.1,
 ('z', 'd'): 0.1,
 ('z', 'i3'): 0.6,
 ('z', 'o'): 0.1,
 ('z', 'y'): 0.4}

from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def total_scores(graph, paths):
  scores = [reduce(mul, [graph[edge] for edge in path], 1) for path in paths]
  return scores

total_scores(tgraph, epaths)
```

However I feel the best approach would be to compute the scores while building the paths: for instance we are counting the weight of ('a','b') six times, while if you do a BFS you will only take it into account once